# Firebase - Auth custom token error auth/network-request-failed

Tags: authentication, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i had tried Firebase 3.5 and 3.6 but have same error. I had read some toipc and i had removed type="submit" in form and add domain in project but it always reports . I had tested it with Firefox 50 and Chrome 54 - I create it in web. My flow is: i call ajax and receive data - If data is true, it will return json include token and sucess = 1. After Ajax call, if have data and data.sucess = 1, i will auth with data.token

> auth/network-request-failed
>
> Thrown if a network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or
> unreachable host) has occurred.

```
<form id="form-login" action="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<!-- Username -->
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" size="20"  />
<!-- Password -->
    <input id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" type="password" size="20"  />
<input id="btn-login" class="h_submit" value="Login" />
```

```
$('#btn-login').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        var username = $.trim(jInputUsername.val());
        var password = $.trim(jInputPassword.val());
        if (!username || !password) {
            alert("Error");
        } else {
            
            $.ajax({
                url: '', 
                type: "post",
                data: {'username': username, 'password': password}, 
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    //        
                    if ($.isPlainObject(data)) {
                        //    On error
                        if (data && data.succeed) {
                            firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(data.token).catch(function(error) {
                              var errorCode = error.code;
                              var errorMessage = error.message;
                              if (errorCode === 'auth/invalid-custom-token') {
                                alert('Token problem.');
                              }
                              alert(errorMessage);
                            });
                            var fullHref = decodeURI(window.location.href);
                            setTimeout(window.location.href = fullHref.replace(hash, ''), 1000);
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function( jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    console.log('Username or passord wrong");
                }
                , dataType:'json'
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: You could also use the ".then" promise like in following: `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(user => console.log(user))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error arises because the `Auth` object takes time to initialise. Though you are using a `timeout` but that does not guarantee the successful initialisation.

According to Firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) the recommeded way to check whether sign in is successful and get the current user is to set an observer on the `Auth` object. So to resolve this error do the redirection `window.location.href` inside the `onAuthStateChanged` observer.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I will try to test it tomorrow. Default, it doesn't have setTimeout, i had inserted it because i think firebase can't complete function and report problem so i had inserted it

Comment: You shouldn't use timeout to wait for completion, because you can't predict how much time it will take for completion and you don't want to wait for so long. I was facing same error a few days back, this method resolved it.